# Exception on delete hits the console in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm having a little bit of trouble with console outputs for a delete statement.

I'm using Grails 2.3.11 for this project.

The idea ist quite simple and works, but there is an unwanted output to the console.

The project enables the user to delete a person, which has no ties to other domain objects. To achieve this, I use the following code:

```
def person = Person.get(params.id)
try {
    person.delete(flush: true)
}
catch (org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    def returnData = [:]
    returnData.put("message", "Person is undeletable")
    returnData.put("success", false)
    render returnData as JSON
}
```

If it doesn't have any ties in the db, the object gets deleted. If it does, it doesn't get deleted, which is what I want!
If an object couldn't be deleted the server response  is a status 200 with the JSON, so that works fine!
But it still sends a stacktrace to the console/log, which is in my opinion unnecessary.

Is there a way to get around that, that I havn't seen?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the relevant excerpt of the stacktrace:

```
| Error 2015-01-29 16:23:38,291 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`table`, CONSTRAINT `FKFC41E6E036872635` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`))
...
| Error 2015-01-29 16:23:38,294 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session

Message: could not delete: [Person#13454]

Caused by MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`table`, CONSTRAINT `FKFC41E6E036872635` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`))
```

Comment: What stacktrace are you getting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed the title before submitting where I put the Exception :( I'll edit the stacktrace in

Comment: Are you sure the `Person` entity is deleted? Try `person.delete(flush: true, failOnError: true)`

Comment: If the `Person` entity doesn't have any connections, it gets deleted.

Comment: To me it seems that nothing is deleted and the error is valid. You get the 200 response because `failOnError` is not enabled, and thus the response is triggered even if the operations has failed. If this is not the case, you need to add some additional info.

Comment: Thanks john, I clarified, what the problem is. The thing is, that the behaviour is totally fine except for the stack trace which gets dumped into the log. I wanted to prevent that with using the try catch statement.